# TypeError: this.inputMedia.pipe is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord bot. I want it so that, when I say one of a couple phrases, it will join the user that sent the message's voice channel, play a random sound, then leave. It uses [discord.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js) and the [pick-random](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pick-random) npm library. Here is the code. Mind that in a different file, server.js, it requires this file and does `client.on('message', randomSound);`

```
const pickRandom = require('pick-random');
const { playUrl } = require('./play-url');

exports.randomSound = function(message) {
  const content = message.content;
  if (content.toLowerCase() === "phrase 2" || 
      content.toLowerCase() === "phrase 1") {
    var soundUrl = pickRandom(
      ['sound url 1',
       'sound url 2',
       'sound url 3',
       'sound url 4'
      ]);
    playUrl(message.member.voiceChannel, soundUrl);
  }  
}
```

Then, in play-url.js:

```
exports.playUrl = function(voiceChannel, soundUrl, options) {

    // If messange sender is in a voice channel
    if (voiceChannel) {
      voiceChannel
        // Join it
        .join()
        .then(connection => {
          // Play the sound
          const sound = connection.playArbitraryInput(soundUrl, options);
          sound.on('end', () => {
            voiceChannel.leave();
            console.log('Done playing');
          });
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

For some reason, I get this error.

```
TypeError: this.inputMedia.pipe is not a function

    at FfmpegProcess.connectStream (/rbd/pnpm-volume/a60d0461-d164-4ade-92da-e09aca748da0/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/prism-media/0.0.3/node_modules/prism-media/src/transcoders/ffmpeg/FfmpegProcess.js:73:21)

    at new FfmpegProcess (/rbd/pnpm-volume/a60d0461-d164-4ade-92da-e09aca748da0/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/prism-media/0.0.3/node_modules/prism-media/src/transcoders/ffmpeg/FfmpegProcess.js:28:14)

    at FfmpegTranscoder.transcode (/rbd/pnpm-volume/a60d0461-d164-4ade-92da-e09aca748da0/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/prism-media/0.0.3/node_modules/prism-media/src/transcoders/ffmpeg/Ffmpeg.js:34:18)

    at MediaTranscoder.transcode (/rbd/pnpm-volume/a60d0461-d164-4ade-92da-e09aca748da0/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/prism-media/0.0.3/node_modules/prism-media/src/transcoders/MediaTranscoder.js:27:31)

    at Prism.transcode (/rbd/pnpm-volume/a60d0461-d164-4ade-92da-e09aca748da0/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/prism-media/0.0.3/node_modules/prism-media/src/Prism.js:13:28)

    at AudioPlayer.playUnknownStream (/rbd/pnpm-volume/a60d0461-d164-4ade-92da-e09aca748da0/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.4.2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/AudioPlayer.js:97:35)

    at VoiceConnection.playArbitraryInput (/rbd/pnpm-volume/a60d0461-d164-4ade-92da-e09aca748da0/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.4.2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/VoiceConnection.js:458:24)

at voiceChannel.join.then.connection (/app/play-url.js:10:36)

    at <anonymous>

    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

Comment: Whats your discord.js version.
You can get the easiest by doing `console.log(require('discord.js').version)`

Comment: In my `package.json`, it's `^11.4.2`, and in your version above, it also outputs `11.4.2`.

Comment: I guess the best fix would be to upgrade to d.js master ( it has a full voice rewrite wich fixes a lot of issues ), that includes breaking changes tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the issue; the `pickRandom()` function outputs an array with the chosen object instead of just the object itself. A strange way to do that, but I fixed it by changing

```js
playUrl(message.member.voiceChannel, soundUrl);
```

to

```js
playUrl(message.member.voiceChannel, soundUrl[0]);
```